# what's the appropriate placeholder for my input

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow, input, model, placeholder

I have a 1k rows and 14 columns dataframe containing numpy arrays like shown below.

Here a subset of 2 rows and 3 columns :

```
[5,4,74,-12] [  78,1,2,-9]    [5 ,1,1,2] 

[10,4,4,-1]  [  8,15,21,-19]  [1,1,0,0]
```

where each cell is a numpy array of shape `(4,1)`.

I couldn't find the right placeholder to input my whole dataframe as it needs to be processed by row batches.

Could anyone have an idea ?

I tried this to find the proper placeholder for my dataframe but its not correct:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,14],name='x') 

with tf.Session() as sess:
     print(sess.run(x,feed_dict={x:Data}))

It gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify in which format your data is available, so I assume it is a numpy array. In this case, you can do it like this:

```
n_columns = 14
n_elements_per_column = 4

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_columns, n_elements_per_column], name='x') 

with tf.Session() as sess:
     print(sess.run(x,feed_dict={x:Data}))
```

Comment: I still have the same error setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @LY-: Can you post your Data variable then? It seems to be something different than a pure numpy array.